# Regex search and replace pattern with modified pattern - Python

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to find a string using regex pattern matching, manipulate it & return it?

For example:

```
mazda mazda6 mazda 6 mazda3 mazda2
```

I want `'mazda6'`,`'mazda3'`,`'mazda2'` to be replaced by `'6'`,`'3'`,`'2'`. I can find them easily enough using regex `(mazda\d)`, however I don't know how to replace them with a modified version of the matched pattern (i.e. the \d should remain).

Ideal output:

```
mazda 6 mazda 6 3 2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can capture the number in regex and use it's back-reference in replacement:

```
str = "mazda mazda6 mazda 6 mazda3 mazda2"

result = re.sub(r'\bmazda(\d+)', r'\1', str)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> print result
'mazda 6 mazda 6 3 2'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wX0xE4/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to require that `mazda` is followed by a number without actually matching it:

```
str = "mazda mazda6 mazda 6 mazda3 mazda2"
re.sub(r'mazda(?=\d+)', r'', str)
```